# Why does the $\tan$ reduction formula have a restriction?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My book says the reduction formula is only valid for an integer $n > 1$. Why? [This derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793105/proving-the-reduction-formula-of-tann-theta) doesn't require $n$ to be an integer or greater than $1$.

Comment: I think you're right, but the reduction formula is generally only useful if n is an integer with $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case where the formula doesn't work is $n=1$ (because of a $0$ in the denominator).  It's perfectly valid to say, e.g.,

$$\int \tan^{5/2}(x)\; dx = - \int \tan^{1/2}(x)\; dx  + \dfrac{\tan^{3/2}(x)}{3/2}+ C$$

(at least on an interval where $\tan(x) > 0$).  It might not be too useful unless you can evaluate one of those integrals by other means (but that can be done).